# Collection does not return the intended results

Tags: magento2, collection

I am working with the collection from a module trying to return specific information. The database has several columns but I only want 2: "region_id" & "default_name". But, every time I run this function, returns nothing and when I do `$CollectionOrigin->getSelect->__toString()` I get the correct resulting SQL command, which returns the correct values when run in the Database.
here's my function, can someone tell me what I'm missing
[image]

Comment: Your module have one table only and you are using that model only?

Comment: @DhirenVasoya i checked the module this originated from, and I'm pretty sure its more than 1 table (3 I think) however, the getSelect() command returns an SQL, that when run on the database, returns the correct results from only ONE of the 3 tables.

Comment: My Question is that, you need to use proper Model where those 2 column are available, so you get your desire result.

Comment: @DhirenVasoya if it was the wrong model wouldn't the SQL generated be for the wrong table? and NOT give me my desired results?

Comment: Can you try with the below code to print the collection data before for-each statement?
var_dump($regionCollectionOrigin->getData();)exit;

Comment: @JitendraPatel this returned an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

1] Fetching collection with single table use the below code.

```
$collection = $this->reservationFactory->create()->getCollection();
$collection->addFieldToFilter('quote_id',$quote_id);
```

2] Fetching product layer collection with EAV tables use the below code.

```
$collection = $layer->getProductCollection();
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('status',1);
```

3] I assume you have a single table then can you modify the code as below.

```
$id = 1234;
$regionCollectionOrigin = $this->_regionFactory->create()->getCollection();
$regionCollectionOrigin->addFieldToFilter('region_id',$id);
var_dump($regionCollectionOrigin->getData();)exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to get the default name and region id

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$region = $objectManager->create('Magento\Directory\Model\Region')
                        ->loadByCode('CA', 'US');
echo "<pre>";
print_r($region->getData());
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [region_id] => 12
    [country_id] => US
    [code] => CA
    [default_name] => California
    [name] => California
)
```

Comment: But i do NOT want to load by code. i want to load using the ID.

Comment: I have posted another answer please check that and I am sure this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Get the default name using region id

```
<?php
 
use Magento\Directory\Model\RegionFactory;
 
class Save extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action 
{
 protected $regionFactory;
 
 public function __construct(
 RegionFactory $regionFactory
 ){
 $this->regionFactory = $regionFactory;
  }
        $regionId = '1';
        public function getRegionData( $regionId ){
         $region = $this->regionFactory->create()->load($regionId);
         echo "<pre>";
         print_r($region->getData());
       }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Array
(
    [region_id] => 1
    [country_id] => US
    [code] => AL
    [default_name] => Alabama
    [name] => Alabama
)
```